# Unable to ping Windows Server using win_ping

Tags: windows, ansible

When I tried to ping my Windows instance using **ansible windows -i hosts.ini -m win_ping** , I got the following error :

```
10.0.72.11 | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "ssl: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='10.0.72.11', port=5986): Max retries exceeded with url: /wsman (Caused by ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x2319990>, 'Connection to 10.0.72.11 timed out. (connect timeout=30)'))",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

My **hosts.ini** file looks like :

```
[windows]
10.0.72.11

[windows:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=Administrator
ansible_ssh_pass=MyPassword123!
ansible_ssh_port=5986
ansible_connection=winrm
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation=ignore
```

May I know where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the same error. In my case WinRM was not enabled properly on Windows host. I ran the PowerShell script on my windows host, resolved the errors by setting variables and flags as mentioned in the "ConfigureRemotingForAnsible.ps1" comments section and the error disappeared.